# How to automatically pass an XPath generated by FirePath to a Javascript function

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, xpath, firebug

I am doing some XPath related work where a user should click any DOM element and it's XPath should get generated. Currently I am using FirePath (Firebug extension), but I need to remove the process of copy-pasting the XPath from there (for automation purposes) and instead pass it to a JavaScript function when the XPath is generated after the click.

Is it possible at all? Can someone guide me in the right direction on how to accomplish this?

Comment: According to [your post in the Firebug discussion group](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/firebug/EyWXt94h1aA/JIdIDOVtTKMJ) I assume you could already fix your problem. So it would be great if you posted an answer how you solved it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution was to modify the `stopInspecting()` function of FirePath. Here's the related code:

```
    stopInspecting: function(inspectingNode, cancelled) {
            this.inspecting = false;
            var latestXpath = getXPathFromNode(inspectingNode);   // getting xpath
            // in Firebug 1.7 the signature of this method changed
            // before there was only on arg: cancelled.
            if (!Firebug.Inspector._resolveInspectingPanelName) {
                cancelled = inspectingNode;
            }
            if(cancelled) {
                this.navigate(this.previousLocation);
                this.fireSIMSBar.selector = this.previousSelector;
                delete this.previousLocation;
                delete this.previousSelector;
            }
            this.fireSIMSBar.reset();
            this.fireSIMSBar.evaluate();

            // Passing xpath to javascript function 
            var doc = Application.activeWindow.activeTab.document;
            var win = doc.defaultView;
            win.wrappedJSObject.myFunction(latestXpath);

            }
     },
```

Answer (score 1):

I see two possibilities how to achieve that:

1. Change the [source code of FirePath](http://code.google.com/p/firepath/source/browse/) to allow exporting the generated XPath.
2. Create a [Selenium IDE](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/projects/ide/) script that first executes the path in Firebug/FirePath and then exports it.